# Lambda function to groupby first substring?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dstream

I am trying to write a lambda function that groups words based on their first substring
So the words are coming in like

```
a,word
b,can
a,eat
c,vegetables
b,if
```

So far I have a lambda function

```
combineddatardd.combineByKey(lambda v:\[v\],lambda x,y:x+\[y\],lambda x,y:x+y).
combineddatardd.pprint(10)
```

But this only gives me not the result I want.
The outcome needs to be :

```
a,word
a,eat
b,can
b,if
c,vegetables
```